# Pass two bundles to same activity

Tags: android, json, android-bundle

I have a list of json array response with multiple userinformation. Created a bundle and successfully passed it to next activity. Created another bundle with user selected date and time.But no luck to second bundle to the same activity because i can be able to pass only one bundle to same activity.

My actual problem is how to pass second bundle in putExtras to same activity

```
Json Response
{
  "userinfo": [
    {
      "address": "Tambaram",
      "name": "Vishranthi"
    },
    {
      "address": "Medavakkam",
      "name": "Sophia" 
    },
 ]
}
```

Bundle creation code:

```
JSONArray infoarray = obj.getJSONArray("Info");
Bundle h = new Bundle();
for (int i = 0; i < infoarray.length(); i++) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    JSONObject infoobject = infoarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = infoobject.getString("name");
    String address = infoobject.getString("address");

    b.putString("name", name);
    b.putString("address", address);

    h.putBundle(Integer.toString(i), b);

    System.out.println(b);
}
Intent i = new Intent(context, Secondpage.class);
Bundle d=new Bundle();
d.putString("date", text1);
d.putString("time", text2);

i.putExtras(h);
System.out.println(h);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: why do you want to use a separate bundle for your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to put two bundles into your intent you have to use

```
Intent putExtra (String name, 
                Bundle value)
```

something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Secondpage.class);
i.putExtra("bundleH", h);
i.putExtra("bundleD", d);
```

[ref](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle))

Comment: Worked Great. Created two bundles as you explained and received it through                                                                                                               Bundle b=this.getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundleD");

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, so the easiest solution would be to pass the json youre parsing into the second activity and the values you want on the second bundle as primitives, then on the second activity parse json into primitive data and retrieve date & time.

Answer (score 0):

instead of create another Bundle to the date and time use the same one

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deserialize a JSONObject or JSONArray, just put it in Bundle as String.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("MyBundle", infoarray.toString());
```

So at next Activity, get the JSONArray

```
JSONArray newJArray = new JSONArray(bundle.getString("MyBundle",""));
```

A little tip: Avoid declare variables inside loops to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the approach a bit:
do this in your first activity your you have the json array

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, Secondpage.class);
        i.putExtra("userinfo", infoarray.toString());
```

and in your second activity do the rest code

```
 if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("userinfo")) {
                try {
                    JSONArray infoarray = new JSONArray(getIntent().getExtras().getString("userinfo"));
                    for (int i = 0; i < infoarray.length(); i++) {
                        ]
                        JSONObject infoobject = infoarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = infoobject.getString("name");
                        String address = infoobject.getString("address");
                       //your code parse user list


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e)

            }
```